# DSL Tools: Create a new Diagram in custom code

Tags: dsl, dsl-tools

I am using DSL Tools for Visual Studio 2005.

I have a DSL where at a certain point I would like to create a new Diagram using custom code.

So far, I was able to create a new Diagram by overwriting the current, already opened diagram. Code follows:

```
FEGeneratorDiagram diag = new FEGeneratorDiagram(ThisElem.Store);
diag.Associate(ThisElem);
FEGeneratorDiagram currentDiag = (FEGeneratorDiagram)ThisElem.Store.ElementDirectory.FindElements<FEGeneratorDiagram>(false)[0];
currentDiag = diag;
```

But, what I would really like to do would be,

to create a new DSL document with a new instance FEGeneratorDiagram and then keep on my logic of adding elements and setting properties.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Create a Store
Type[] modelTypes = new Type[] { typeof(CoreDesignSurfaceDomainModel), typeof(FEGeneratorDomainModel) };
Store store = new Store(modelTypes);
RootElement root;
using (Transaction t =
store.TransactionManager.BeginTransaction("Create Elements"))
{
    root = FEGeneratorSerializationHelper.Instance.LoadModel(store, diagramPath, null, null);
    t.Commit();
}
//Do whatever custom things you want!

SerializationResult result = new SerializationResult();
//Save the file
FEGeneratorSerializationHelper.Instance.SaveModel(result, root, diagramPath);
```